# How to make correct Get Request using rest-assured?

Tags: rest-assured

I do Get request to api

public class Req1 {

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false));
    Response response = given()
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("PWT", "123123123123")
            .header("Referer", "https://xxxxxxx.ru/")
            .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors")
            .header("X-Auth-Token", "123123123123")
            .header("X-User-Lang","rus")
            .body("dateEnd=2019-09-17&dateStart=2019-09-17&limit=100&officeCode=270&offset=0&onlyEmpty=false&typeBasis=\n")
            .baseUri("https://xxxxx.ru")
            .get();
    System.out.println(response.body().asString());
}
```

}

But request doesnt use body -> i got result without dateEnd,officeCode etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this . this will print the request. as you can see, Body do contain what you are sending.

i think, code is working as you wrote it. Please check whether the body is right or not.

```
Response response = given().header("Accept", "application/json").header("PWT", "123123123123")
                .header("Referer", "https://xxxxxxx.ru/").header("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors")
                .header("X-Auth-Token", "123123123123").header("X-User-Lang", "rus")
                .body("dateEnd=2019-09-17&dateStart=2019-09-17&limit=100&officeCode=270&offset=0&onlyEmpty=false&typeBasis=\n")
                .baseUri("https://xxxxx.ru").log().all().get();
        System.out.println(response.body().asString());
```

Comment: I've checked the code, that u send:  result as above (without .body used)

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Way of Implementing Call:**

```
package api.restassured.libarary.basics.problems;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static io.restassured.config.EncoderConfig.encoderConfig;

public class getCall {

    public static  RequestSpecification requestSpecification;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setRequestSpecification(){

        Map<String ,String> hearders = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                put("Accept", "application/json");
                put("PWT", "123123123123");
                put("Referer", "https://xxxxxxx.ru/");
                put("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
                put("X-Auth-Token", "123123123123");
                put("X-User-Lang","rus");
        }};

        RestAssuredConfig restAssuredConfig = new RestAssuredConfig();
        restAssuredConfig.encoderConfig(encoderConfig().
                                    appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false));


         requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder().
                                                    addHeaders(hearders).
                                                    setConfig(restAssuredConfig).
                                                    setBaseUri("https://xxxxx.ru").build();
    }


   @Test
    public void getCall(){

      String requestBody = "dateEnd=2019-09-17&dateStart=2019-09-17&limit=100&officeCode=270&offset=0&onlyEmpty=false&typeBasis=";

      Response response = given().
                              spec(requestSpecification).
                              body(requestBody).
                          when().
                                get().
                          then().
                              extract().response();

       System.out.println(response.body().asString());

   }



}
```